# Processing to grasshopper with oscP5

Tags: java, processing, osc, oscp5

I’m trying to see if I can link a sketch made in processing to grasshopper using oscP5. The sketch is a sphere of points outlined in the first half of this Coding Train video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RkuBWEkBrZA

The code before I’ve started to link it with oscP5 appears to be working fine:

```
import peasy.*;

PeasyCam cam;

PVector[][] globe;
int total = 20;

void setup() {
  size(600, 600, P3D);
  cam = new PeasyCam(this, 500);

  globe = new PVector[total+1][total+1];
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  fill(255);
  lights();

  float r = 200;

  for (int i = 0; i < total+1; i++) {
    float lat = map(i, 0, total, 0, PI);
    for (int j = 0; j < total+1; j++) {
      float lon = map(j, 0, total, 0, TWO_PI);
      float x = r * sin(lat) * cos(lon);
      float y = r * sin(lat) * sin(lon);
      float z = r * cos(lat);   
      globe[i][j] = new PVector(x, y, z);        
    }
  }
  noFill();   
  for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    beginShape(TRIANGLE_STRIP); 
    for (int j = 0; j < total+1; j++) {
      PVector v1 = globe[i][j];
      stroke(255);
      strokeWeight(2);
      vertex(v1.x, v1.y, v1.z);   

      PVector v2 = globe[i+1][j];
      vertex(v2.x, v2.y, v2.z); 
    }
    endShape();
  }
}
```

However when I try to implement oscP5 its not quite working. My grasshopper file is recieving the skech fine however the points aren’t correct so I must have a problem with what data I’m sending with but I cant seem to figure out what I should be sending instead. The code takes the values of a stated radius, longitude and latitude and converts it into an x, y, z co-ordinate and I was trying to get oscP5 to send those x, y, z coordinates.

Does anyone have any ideas? The code so far is below.

```
//import necessary libraries
import oscP5.*;
import netP5.*;

OscP5 oscP5;
NetAddress myRemoteLocation;

//import camera
import peasy.*;

PeasyCam cam;

// message to send
String message;

PVector[][] sphere;
int total = 20;

float lat;
float lon;

void setup() {
  size(600, 600, P3D);
  cam = new PeasyCam(this, 500);

  sphere = new PVector[total+1][total+1];

//send message from this port
  oscP5 = new OscP5(this,12000);      
//send message to this port
  myRemoteLocation = new NetAddress("127.0.0.1",12001);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  fill(255);
  lights();

  float r = 200;

  for (int i = 0; i < total+1; i++) {
    float lat = map(i, 0, total, 0, PI);
    for (int j = 0; j < total+1; j++) {
      float lon = map(j, 0, total, 0, TWO_PI);
      float x = r * sin(lat) * cos(lon);
      float y = r * sin(lat) * sin(lon);
      float z = r * cos(lat);   
      sphere[i][j] = new PVector(x, y, z);        
    }
  }
  noFill();    
  for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    beginShape(TRIANGLE_STRIP); 
    for (int j = 0; j < total+1; j++) {
      PVector v1 = sphere[i][j];
      stroke(255);
      strokeWeight(2);
      vertex(v1.x, v1.y, v1.z);   

      PVector v2 = sphere[i+1][j];
      vertex(v2.x, v2.y, v2.z); 
    }
    endShape();
  }

// osc message
  OscMessage myMessage = new OscMessage("/hello world");


for (int j = 0; j < total+1; j++) {
//message to send 
message  = "x = " + String.valueOf(r * sin(lat) * cos(lon)) + "; " + 
           "y = " + String.valueOf(r * sin(lat) * sin(lon))+ "; " +
           "z = " + String.valueOf(r * cos(lat))+ "; " ;

    myMessage.add(String.valueOf(r * sin(lat) * cos(lon)));
    myMessage.add(String.valueOf(r * sin(lat) * sin(lon))); 
    myMessage.add(String.valueOf(r * cos(lat))); 
  }

//print message
  println(message);
//send message
  oscP5.send(myMessage, myRemoteLocation);
}
```

I believe the error is in this section of the code

```
for (int j = 0; j < total+1; j++) {
//message to send 
message  = "x = " + String.valueOf(r * sin(lat) * cos(lon)) + "; " + 
           "y = " + String.valueOf(r * sin(lat) * sin(lon))+ "; " +
           "z = " + String.valueOf(r * cos(lat))+ "; " ;

    myMessage.add(String.valueOf(r * sin(lat) * cos(lon)));
    myMessage.add(String.valueOf(r * sin(lat) * sin(lon))); 
    myMessage.add(String.valueOf(r * cos(lat))); 
  }
```

Any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 2):

The values of the global variables `float lat;` are never `float lon;` set, because in the nested `for` loops, 2 new local variables  (in the loop block scopes) are declared:

```
for (int i = 0; i < total+1; i++) {
float lat = map(i, 0, total, 0, PI);
    for (int j = 0; j < total+1; j++) {
        float lon = map(j, 0, total, 0, TWO_PI);

        // [...]
    }
}
```

Note, `float lat = ...` declares a new variable, `lat = ...` would be an assignment to the existing variable `lat`.

But using the global variables instead of setting new ones, won't change anything, because when the message is sent, then the variables `lat` and `lon` would have the value of the last iteration of the nested loops.

You have to implement 2 new loops and you have to recalculate the values for `lat` and `lon`. The print statement at after the loop makes not any sense, because it will print the last coordinates only.

The code should look somehow like this:

```
// osc message
OscMessage myMessage = new OscMessage("/hello world");

for (int i = 0; i < total+1; i++) {
    float lat = map(i, 0, total, 0, PI);
    for (int j = 0; j < total+1; j++) {
        float lon = map(j, 0, total, 0, TWO_PI);

        float x = r * sin(lat) * cos(lon);
        float y = r * sin(lat) * sin(lon);
        float z = r * cos(lat);
        println("(", i, ",", j, ") : x =" , x, "y = ", y, "z = ", z);

        myMessage.add(String.valueOf(x));
        myMessage.add(String.valueOf(y)); 
        myMessage.add(String.valueOf(z)); 
    }
}

//send message
oscP5.send(myMessage, myRemoteLocation);
```